# Several if conditions, check if no one is true

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, if-statement

I'm not sure how to put together this code with a few if/else statements.

I check a field if it is not empty - in that case I also check if the value match a certain text.

This procedure is repeated two more times with two more fields.

The last thing is to add a new field **if** there where no matches in the if conditions.
I need to rewrite this somehow, I didn't figure it out. I thought I could set a variable to "true" if there was a match. But I'm breaking some scope rules I guess. So the idea with my "$alreadyexists" variable is totally wrong.

How should I carry out this thing?

```
$textcontent = "Unique text in a unique field";

$subfieldvalue1 = get_post_meta($page_id,$subfield1 );
$subfieldvalue2 = get_post_meta($page_id,$subfield2 );
$subfieldvalue8 = get_post_meta($page_id,$subfield8 );

$alreadyexists = false;

if(!empty($subfieldvalue1)){
    if($subfieldvalue1[0] === $textcontent){
            $alreadyexists = true;
    }
}
if(!empty($subfieldvalue2)){
    if($subfieldvalue2[0] === $textcontent){
        $alreadyexists = true;
    }
}
if(!empty($subfieldvalue8)){
    if($subfieldvalue8[0] === $textcontent){
        $alreadyexists = true;
    }
}
if($alreadyexists = false){
    //add new field with text content!
}
```

Comment: I think you are doing some validations, you might start to consider to redesign your structure as it will be incredibly hard to maintain this kind of style in a large scale project. Maybe you can ask a question more about how to handle validations efficiently.

Comment: @RyanVincent I think it's WordPress

Comment: @Ryan Vincent : it's a wordpress function that gets the value of a meta key from a specific page.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know what it was - is appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `get_post_meta` returns an array with at least one index when it is not empty, your code should work. FYI , the variable you named `$alreadyexists` is called a *flag variable*. You can optimize your code by using `if else` (so the parser will stop when one condition evaluates to `true`) and you can enhance readability by chaining your nested conditions in one `if` statement with the `&&` operator. But while we're at it, you're better off writing a function that works with any number of fields (see below).

Note that in your current code, `$alreadyexists` will even be false if all values exist, it will only be true if one of them exactly matches `$textcontent`.

```
function compareToValue($checks, $comparer) {
  $flag = false;
  foreach ($checks as $check) 
    if (!empty($check) && $check[0] === $comparer)
       $flag = true;
  return $flag;
}

$fields = array(
   get_post_meta($page_id, $subfield1),
   get_post_meta($page_id, $subfield2),
   get_post_meta($page_id, $subfield8)
);

if(!compareToValue($fields, 'your unique string')) {
   // ... run code if no perfect match
};
```

Comment: This works great! Maybe I could remove the "flag" and just return true or false though (haven't tried it though)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separated method, receiving as input a list of "$subfieldX" and $page_id. So the pseudocode is:

```
boolean checkingMethod(list_of_entries, $page_id){
    for(all entries in list_of_entries) {
        $subfieldvalue = get_post_meta($page_id,$entry );
        if(!empty($subfieldvalue)){
            if($subfieldvalue[0] === $textcontent){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As soon you find one true, you know there is nothing to do. The idea is to have a piece of code for N entries.